# Is there a way to link specific lines (line numbers) of your code together in Xcode for easy reference?

Tags: xcode

I am fairly new to Xcode and I am wondering if there is a way to link two separate lines such as if I have a do while loop I can 1. see which line it is associated with 2. see which 'do' line number is associated with which 'while' line number. I know this is a subjective question and maybe not fitting for this kind of platform, however I'm unsure where to ask it. I'd appreciate the help though.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to ask here…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is built into Xcode. In properties, turn on the "Code folding ribbon" in the "Text Editing" pane:

[image: Code folding ribbon option]

This lets you see immediately what lines of code are part of a block, or collapse sections so you can focus on the structure. Look at the Editor menu, under "Code Folding" for options and keystrokes.